# Connection between Chladni Plates and Algebraic Topology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics

Does anybody know of a connection between Chladni plates and algebraic topology? Any published research on the subject? I am interested to know if Chladni plates (or surfaces) can be explained/expressed in algebraic-topological terms.

Chladni Plates:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Chladni#Chladni_figures

Chladni interference surfaces:
http://paulbourke.net/geometry/chladni/

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to believe there should be a connection?